# Defining a Racket Function?

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, racket, factorial

I'm supposed to define the function `n! (N-Factorial)`. The thing is I don't know how to. 
Here is what I have so far, can someone please help with this? I don't understand the conditionals in Racket, so an explanation would be great!

```
(define fact (lambda (n) (if (> n 0)) (* n < n)))
```

Comment: You should not be trying to juggle conditionals and recursion at the same time.  Trying to learn both at the same time is madness.  See a tutorial that talks about these separately.   http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_prologue.html#%28part._pro-cond%29 may help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to take a good look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html#%28part._.Simple_.Branching__if%29) first, this is a very simple example but you have to understand the basics before attempting a solution, and make sure you know how to write a recursive procedure. Some comments:

```
(define fact 
  (lambda (n)
    (if (> n 0)
        ; a conditional must have two parts:
        ; where is the consequent? here goes the advance of the recursion
        ; where is the alternative? here goes the base case of the recursion
        ) 
    (* n < n))) ; this line is outside the conditional, and it's just wrong
```

Notice that the last expression is incorrect, I don't know what it's supposed to do, but as it is it'll raise an error. Delete it, and concentrate on writing the body of the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with scheme (or lisp) is to understand each little bit between each set of brackets as you build them up into more complex forms.

So lets start with the conditionals.  `if` takes 3 arguments.  It evaluates the first, and if that's true, if returns the second, and if the first argument is false it returns the third.

```
(if #t "some value" "some other value") ; => "some value"
(if #f "some value" "some other value") ; => "some other value"
(if (<= 1 0) "done" "go again") ; => "go again"
```

`cond` would work too - you can read the racket introduction to conditionals here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax-overview.html#%28part._.Conditionals_with_if__and__or__and_cond%29

You can define functions in two different ways.  You're using the anonymous function approach, which is fine, but you don't need a lambda in this case, so the simpler syntax is:

```
(define (function-name arguments) result)
```

For example:

```
(define (previous-number n)
  (- n 1))
(previous-number 3) ; => 2
```

Using a lambda like you have achieves the same thing, using different syntax (don't worry about any other differences for now):

```
(define previous-number* (lambda (n) (- n 1)))
(previous-number* 3) ; => 2
```

By the way - that '*' is just another character in that name, nothing special (see http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax-overview.html#%28part._.Identifiers%29). A '!' at the end of a function name often means that that function has side effects, but n! is a fine name for your function in this case.

So lets go back to your original question and put the function definition and conditional together.  We'll use the "recurrence relation" from the wiki definition because it makes for a nice recursive function: If n is less than 1, then the factorial is 1.  Otherwise, the factorial is n times the factorial of one less than n.  In code, that looks like:

```
(define (n! n)
  (if (<= n 1) ; If n is less than 1,
    1 ; then the factorial is 1
    (* n (n! (- n 1))))) ; Otherwise, the factorial is n times the factorial of one less than n.
```

That last clause is a little denser than I'd like, so lets just work though it down for n = 2:
    (define n 2)
    (* n (n! (- n 1)))
    ; =>
    (* 2 (n! (- 2 1)))
    (* 2 (n! 1))
    (* 2 1)
    2

Also, if you're using Racket, it's really easy to confirm that it's working as we expect:

```
(check-expect (n! 0) 1)
(check-expect (n! 1) 1)
(check-expect (n! 20) 2432902008176640000)
```